# vhdl program for ripple carry adder showing warning about component instance not bound

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

```
architecture rtl of ripple_carry_adder is

  component full_adder is
    port (
      i_bit1  : in  std_logic;
      i_bit2  : in  std_logic;
      i_carry : in  std_logic;
      o_sum   : out std_logic;
      o_carry : out std_logic);
  end component full_adder;

  signal w_CARRY : std_logic_vector(g_WIDTH downto 0);
  signal w_SUM   : std_logic_vector(g_WIDTH-1 downto 0);


begin

  w_CARRY(0) <= '0';                    -- no carry input on first full adder

  SET_WIDTH : for ii in 0 to g_WIDTH-1 generate
    i_FULL_ADDER_INST : full_adder
      port map (
        i_bit1  => i_add_term1(ii),
        i_bit2  => i_add_term2(ii),
        i_carry => w_CARRY(ii),
        o_sum   => w_SUM(ii),
        o_carry => w_CARRY(ii+1)
        );
  end generate SET_WIDTH;

  o_result <= w_CARRY(g_WIDTH) & w_SUM;  -- VHDL Concatenation

end rtl;
```

using this architecture i compiled and analyzed successfully.but when elaborating it is showing

```
warning: component instance "i_full_adder_inst" is not bound
warning: (in default configuration of ripple_carry_adder(rtl))
```

and i am getting zero waveform throughout. what i need to do??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, provide more information about your question. Where is `i_add_term1()` coming from? Where is your `o_result` going to (i.e., where are their definition)? What is your testbench? And any other information you find essential to understand your problem.

Comment: Your simulator doesn't know where the architecture of ``full_adder`` is and can't bind it for the final elaboration. That's why it ends up as a non functional black box.

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), *what i need to do??* isn't a specific problem telling what you're having trouble with. You haven't taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), your code isn't a [mcve] not allowing the problem to be replicated nor providing full error/warning messages (here specifying the unbound component `full_adder`). Practically speaking analyze entity `full_adder` with an architecture before elaborating `ripple_carry_adder`. A [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can head off non-useful comments.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Your question is clear enough, Shareefa. Any experienced VHDL programmer encountered the same problem and the same kind of warning. No need for an MCVE here. See my answer for a detailed explanation, but please note that searching "_VHDL component instance not bound_" in your favourite search engine would probably have solved your problem with less effort for you and for SO contributors. Searching the Internet with your error or warning messages (after removal of too specific user identifiers) frequently leads to the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can't be replicated without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example]. Here at least including the entity declaration for `ripple_carry_adder` and the actual complete warnings:

When adding for example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ripple_carry_adder is
    generic ( g_WIDTH:  natural := 4);  -- a default value for convenience
    port (
        i_add_term1:    in  std_logic_vector (g_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        i_add_term2:    in  std_logic_vector (g_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        o_result:       out std_logic_vector (g_WIDTH downto 0)
    );
end entity;
```

the warnings (in their entirety):

```
ghdl -a ripple_carry_adder.vhdl
ghdl -e ripple_carry_adder
ripple_carry_adder.vhdl:34:5:warning: component instance "i_full_adder_inst" of 'full_adder' is not bound
[-Wbinding]   ripple_carry_adder.vhdl:13:14:warning: (in default configuration of ripple_carry_adder(rtl)) [-Wbinding]
```

Here telling us the name of the entity not bound. Line 13 is the component declaration for `full_adder`. Line 34 is the component instantiation which when attempting to produce an implicit binding indication in a component configuration isn't found.

It's not illegal to elaborate a design with unbound components resulting in a  binding indication that is open. Allowing unbound components can be useful during incremental development in top down design.

See IEEE Std 1076-2008
3.4.3 Component configuration:

> If a given component instance is unbound in the corresponding block, then any explicit component configuration for that instance that does not contain an explicit binding indication will contain an implicit, default binding indication (see 7.3.3). Similarly, if a given component instance is unbound in the corresponding block, then any implicit component configuration for that instance will contain an implicit, default binding indication.

You don't provide a configuration declaration with a component configuration providing a binding indication. An implicit component configuration will contain a default binding indication.

7.3.3 Default binding indication

> In certain circumstances, a default binding indication will apply in the absence of an explicit binding indication. The default binding indication consists of a default entity aspect, together with a default generic map aspect and a default port map aspect, as appropriate.
>
> If no visible entity declaration has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component, then the default entity aspect is open. A visible entity declaration is the first entity declaration, if any, in the following list:
>
> > a) An entity declaration that has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component and that is directly visible (see 12.3),
> >
> > b) An entity declaration that has the same simple name as that of the instantiated component and that would be directly visible in the absence of a directly visible (see 12.3) component declaration with the same simple name as that of the entity declaration, or
> >
> > c) An entity declaration denoted by L.C, where L is the target library and C is the simple name of the instantiated component. The target library is the library logical name of the library containing the design unit in which the component C is declared.
>
> These visibility checks are made at the point of the absent explicit binding indication that causes the default binding indication to apply.

During elaboration (here the static linking part of linking and loading) assembling the model a VHDL tool will search for an entity declaration that has the same name (here `full_adder`).

If an entity with an architecture for `full_adder` is found during elaboration it will be bound by the default binding indication:

```
ghdl -a full_adder.vhdl
ghdl -a ripple_carry_adder.vhdl
ghdl -e ripple_carry_adder
```

No warnings and with a testbench if the model drives full_adder outputs you'll see valid signal levels. (Without a testbench, simulating will only show there are no composite matching element errors and all the types are correct. The analysis order of full_adder and ripple_carry_adder is not important as long as both are analyzed before ripple_carry_adder is elaborated.

What the warnings are telling you is either your component name doesn't match a visible entity name, possibly the entity hasn't been analyzed into a reference library.

Here's the full_adder I genned up to demonstrate:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity full_adder is
  port (
    i_bit1:   in  std_logic;
    i_bit2:   in  std_logic;
    i_carry:  in  std_logic;
    o_sum:    out std_logic;
    o_carry:  out std_logic
  );
end entity full_adder;

architecture foo of full_adder is
begin
    o_sum <= i_carry xor i_bit1 xor i_bit2;
    o_carry <= (i_carry and i_bit1) or 
               (i_carry and i_bit2) or 
               (i_bit1 and i_bit2);
end architecture;
```

There can also be elaboration errors. The component declaration and entity declaration must match, the formals found in a generic map aspect or port map aspect in the instantiation must correspond to the entity declaration, the modes must agree, there has to be a matching element for each element of a composite formal and actual in an association list. ...

Answer (score 0):

A *component* is a declaration, a bit like a function prototype in other programming languages. It tells the compiler what the interface of a sub-circuit looks like. It is enough for the compiler but it is not self-sufficient. At one point (*elaboration*) it must be associated (*bound*) to a real sub-circuit description, that is, an *entity*-*architecture* pair. Some tools can perform such associations based on names: if and only if an *entity* exists, is visible (has already been compiled in a declared *library*), has exactly the same name as the *component* and has one and only one *architecture*, the tool selects this one and associates it to all instances of the *component*.

Else, or if your tool does not perform such associations by default, you will have to specify this yourself using a *configuration specification*:

```
library LIB;
...
architecture rtl of ripple_carry_adder is
  component full_adder is
    ...
  end component full_adder;

  for all: full_adder use entity LIB.E(A);

  signal w_CARRY : std_logic_vector(g_WIDTH downto 0);
  ...
```

where:

- `LIB` is a library. It may be `work` if it is the same library as the one in which you are compiling your `ripple_carry_adder`. Declaring `library work` is not needed because `work` is implicitly always declared.
- `E` is an entity name.
- `A` is the name of an architecture of `E`.
- `E` and `A` must have been compiled in `LIB` **before** you elaborate `ripple_carry_adder`; the tool needs them.

There are other ways to solve this kind of issues (*configuration* design units or entity instantiations) but this one should be enough for your current problem.

One last note about the tool's behaviour you observed: if you don't provide this *configuration specification* and the tool couldn't use a default strategy to bind the component's instantiations to `entity-architecture` pairs, a warning is issued to inform you that some component's instantiations are left unbound. These instances are considered as black boxes and their outputs are not driven during simulation. This is what you see in your waveforms.